# Passing a file URI from sdcard to an ACTION_VIEW Intent

Tags: android, uri, android-fileprovider

I'm updating one of my apps for Android 6 and above. The app lets you attach a file to its data to provide further information. This can be an Image from taken in-app with the camera, and Image from the gallery, or a random file from the file system. I have a ListView that shows the attached files and their metadata and with `onItemClick` I want to show them to the user. I used to get the URI for that file with

```
Uri.fromFile(f)
```

but this is no longer supported as I understand it. Now my code looks like this

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    doc = getItem(arg2);
    File f = doc.getFile(context);

    if (f.exists()) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        String mime = "";

        try {

            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, android.support.v4.BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", f);

            mime = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(new FileInputStream(f));
            if (mime == null) mime = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(f.getName());

            myIntent.setDataAndType(uri, mime);
            context.startActivity(myIntent);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else {
       //Error handling
    }
}
```

This works fine with files on the phone storage. But since FileProvider does not work with files on mountable storage, it will throw an Exception. My question is: how do I get the file URI without using FileProvider?

Comment: I am afraid you cannot do this anymore(pass file uri through Intent without fileprovider). You will get FileUriExposedException

Comment: You should make your own ContentProvider. Then you can serve/provide what you want. FileProvider is very limited.

Comment: Dave, can you give a source for the statement that "FileProvider does not work with files on mountable storage"?

Comment: @greenapps, could you point to an example of what you suggested?

Comment: Google for public parcelfiledescriptor openfile(uri uri string mode)

Comment: @LarsH, removable storage is not supported as you can read after `The <paths> element must contain one or more of the following child elements: ` in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html

Comment: @greenapps: OK, I was hoping for something a lot more definitive. `<external-path>` and `<external-files-path>` represent files in "the external storage area." External storage can include removable storage, and in fact "the" external storage is removable storage on some versions of Android, though certainly not all and probably not most recent versions. But it sounds like these elements are limited to "the" external storage, so it wouldn't work on many recent devices.

Comment: `External storage can include removable storage, and in fact "the" external storage is removable storage on some versions of Android,` Only on very old Android devices/versions. Nowadays never.

Comment: Unfortunately some developers' "very old" is others' current customer base. So it's important to qualify general statements.